# How to add multiple sub fields for main field in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I want to modify Mongoose schema for order management system. How to update my schema which can be make possible to order multiple foods for same customer(from one post request).

ex - customer1 wants to order -
2 Fried-rice and 1 pizza`

```
`const OrderSchema = new Schema({
    cusName:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,'must provide name'],
        trim:true,
        maxlength:[20,'name can not be more than 20 charectors']
    },
    foodName:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,'must provide name'],
        trim:true,
        maxlength:[20,'name can not be more than 20 charectors']
    },
    quntity:{
        type:Number,
        required:[true,'must provide name'],
        trim:true,
    },
    orderTime:{
        type:Number,
        required:[true,'must provide name'],
        trim:true,
    }


});
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change to

```
const OrderSchema = new Schema({
  cusName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'must provide name'],
    trim: true,
    maxlength: [20, 'name can not be more than 20 charectors'],
  },
  request: [
    {
      foodName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'must provide name'],
        trim: true,
        maxlength: [20, 'name can not be more than 20 charectors'],
      },
      quntity: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'must provide name'],
        trim: true,
      },
      orderTime: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'must provide name'],
        trim: true,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

We can allow customers to add more requests